# Execution hangs when MVC client but works when client is console app or test project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I have a MVC5 project that is using a service and repository in a class library project. When I run/debug the following code as a MVC project, the execution hangs at "return await client.GetAsync(url);" in the repository. No exception is thrown.

If I call the same service code and repository code from a unit test or console application, then the code works fine.

What is wrong with the code or what am I doing wrong?

//File: TestController.cs

```
public ActionResult Index(string q)
{
    //Code

    var mySvc = new MyService();
    var svcResponse = mySvc.GetAsync(q).Result;

    //More code
}
```

//File: MyService.cs

```
public async Task<MyResponse> GetAsync(string q)
{
    var myRepo = new MyRepository();
    var response = await myRepo.GetAsync(q);
    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyResponse>(json);
}
```

//File: MyRepository.cs

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string q)
{
    var url = URL_CONSTANT + q;
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        return await client.GetAsync(url);   //Execution hangs here when MVC!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should make your controller method async instead of blocking on .Result (which causes a deadlock). Your controller action should be something like this

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string q)
    {
        //Code

        var mySvc = new MyService();
        var svcResponse = await mySvc.GetAsync(q);

        //More code
    }
```

See for example here for more details http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: Thanks. My MVC code is now working. However, I had to make a small change to the method signature. I changed "IActionResult" to "ActionResult".

Comment: I had a similar problem and this answer helped me a lot. However the thing I still not get about async/await is at what point you stop adding async and await to your call stack? At some point you might want to actually process the results obtained... (In my case an XML document periodically loaded by an application in residing in the tray using a custom application context...)

Comment: In the example above //More code - is where you can actually process the result of the async call to mySvc. At this point you already have svcResponse and you can process it synchronously if that's what you mean

Comment: Thanks! I think I start to slowly get it. My mistake was thinking that without calling ".Result" you will end up with Task<T> instead of T. However now I see that var svcResponse is actually of type T. It only becomes Task<T> again after you return it from the method due to the "async", I guess...